# sending value(a string) from html input to python script (views.py) with Django

Tags: python, html, django

I have a sentence that was made in java in html (var Output).
I want to send this var to views.py to analyse. I saw several similar posts in "stackoverflow" and follow the instructions. still I do not get the response. here is part of my code:
Hope you could help me please;

**ODMS2FixEnd.html**

```
<div>
    ....
    <form id="Sertegh"  name="OUTPUT" method= 'POST' action="{% url 'Calculator' %}">
    {% csrf_token %} <input id="outputtext1" name="outputtext1">
    </form>
    ...
</div>

<script>
     function....
         document.getElementById("outputtext1").value = OutPut;
              ...
</script>
```

**urls.py**

```
...
    url(r'^myprojects/ODMS2FixEnd', blog_views.ODMS2FixEnd, name= 'Calculator'),
...
```

**views.py:**
In here I have tried many things one is this:

```
def ODMS2FixEnd(request):
    if 'outputtext1' in request.POST:
        StringInput0 = request.POST.get('outputtext1')
        print(StringInput0) #just to check
        print("OK") #just to check
        return render(request, 'ODMS2FixEnd.html', {'StringInput0'})

    else:
        print("NOOOOOOO") #just to check
        return render(request, 'ODMS2FixEnd.html')
```

Comment: so print(StringInput0) returns nothing or what?

Comment: No it just print "NOOOOOOO"

Comment: The input field in your html needs to have a **value** of _outputtext1_. Maybe that helps.

Comment: And also you need to learn about how to handle post requests. Start it like this: `if request.method == "POST:"` and then you can handle the post request. Some good links for that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qecJX8W968k and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wzZiONbtwiA

Comment: @Soban thank you for the comment. I learned from the Youtube link and now I am facing new problem. I post another answer below, would you please help me. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had practice your advice and learned deeper. I now write the below code, But when I want to submit the value inside the input tag,  page pops up with 403 CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.. would you please tell me whats wrong

here is my new code:

**views.py**

```
class ODMS2FixEndView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'ODMS2FixEnd.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = HomeForm()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    @csrf_exempt
    def post(self,request):
        form = HomeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("YESSSS")
            text = request.form['post']
            print(text)
            form = HomeForm()
            args = {'form': form, 'text': text}
            return render(request, self.template_name, args)
        else:
            print("NOOOO")
            return render(request, self.template_name)
```

**ODMS2FixEnd.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% extends 'base.html' %}
<meta name="csrf_token" content="{{ csrf_token }}">

....

        <div id="forID" class="container">
            <form method="post" id="form1ID" action="">{% csrf_token %}
                <input type="text" id="OUtPUTCal">
                <button type="submit"> Calculate</button>

            </form>
            <h2>{{ text }}</h2>

        </div>

        <script>
            .....
            document.getElementById("OUtPUTCal").value=TEXT4;

        }
            ......
        </script>
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
....
url(r'^myprojects/ODMS2FixEnd', TemplateView.as_view(template_name = 
'ODMS2FixEnd.html'), name='ODMS2FixEnd'),
....
```

**form.py**

```
from django import forms

class HomeForm(forms.Form):
    post = forms.CharField()
```

Comment: still not working::Method Not Allowed (POST): /myprojects/ODMS2FixEnd.html
Method Not Allowed: /myprojects/ODMS2FixEnd.html

Answer (score 0):

Answering this from my phone so hope you understand. I will give a short answer on how to handle data on post, but search on how to do this as well to get deeper understanding.

```
if request.method == "post":
    var = request.form.get("id", none)
```